# Struct for JSON objects in GO

Tags: json, go

I'm learning GO and when defining structs for working with JSON like below.

```
type List struct {
    ID   string `datastore:"-"`
    Name string
}
```

I see that there is this text in between ` sign. I have not been able to find an explanation what that signifies.

Things seem to work even without those.

Comment: This question is a duplicate, but this question has better wording.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are **struct tags** used in Marshal'ing Go struct into JSON. In JSON, unlike Go, fields are in lowercase strings. Therefore, most use cases would be

```
type List struct {
    ID   string `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}
```

In JSON

```
{
  "id": "some id",
  "name": "some name"
}
```

See post [here](https://medium.com/code-zen/rest-apis-server-in-go-and-redis-66e9cb80a71b)

Comment: Sorry it's actually "struct tags". Edited!